# SSRS Optional parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm not seeing another thread that quite encompasses my scenario: the report I'm modifying has a parameter that I want to make optional, but it is comprised of 3 fields. There is a first name and last name field in which you can start typing, and with the use of a `LIKE` operator, the actual parameter (Authority) used in the main data pull populates with options that match:

[image]

So I've attempted ensuring that the parameters (all 3) have the 'allow blank' and 'allow NULL' checkboxes marked. I've also modified that parameter within the dataset properties to account for NULL:

[image]

Lastly, my main query's WHERE clause has the following line: `and (data.AuthorityName = @Authority or @Authority is null)`

When I declare this variable and set it to NULL, the query does exactly what I want it to, it pulls the data irrespective of what's in this column. But for some reason, I cannot get the report to pull anything. I click View Report and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: If, literally, nothing happens, then your report isn't running. If it were you'd see, at least for a brief moment, the loading icon.

Comment: Precisely. I'm not even seeing the loading icon. I know I'm clicking the button, because when I do, it resets the NULL checkbox next to my param and I have to mark it again.

Comment: So something *does* happen.

Comment: In the strictest technical sense, yes. But nothing is happening as far as producing an output.

Comment: I've just made a slight adjustment that makes my report work. I opted to make my variable a multi-value param and select all the options that I know should be included, and I'm getting the results I need. However, I would love to know what the issue could be regardless?

Comment: We'd need more details really. A query and sample data that is representative, along with the queries and expression (s) you are using.

Comment: Understood. I was hoping there might be some "did you check X?" as some minor detail that facilitates my intention, as opposed to getting elbow deep into the entirety of my report structure. I suppose I'll leave it as-is (especially since I just verified it worked and sent the subscription I needed). I appreciate your time nonetheless.

Comment: I suspect your parameter when "blank" is not an empty string but nothing/NULL. In your report expression you test for an empty string and then pass `nothing` if true. So you could either set the default value to an empty string `""` or check for both in your parameter expression with something like `IIF(LEN(Parameters.Authority.Value) = 0 ....`